# How to implement a NxM CUDA matrix multiplication?

Tags: c, cuda

I already have searched about this on several pages, but I only found implementations for NxN matrices.

How can I define a `dimBlock` and a `dimGrid` to compute this?
Also, how to play with:

```
int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
```

with their respective limits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a naive matrix multiplication, it's pretty trivial.  Non-square matrix multiplication must be of the form:

```
C(rowsA x colsB) = A(rowsA x colsA) x B(colsA x colsB)
   (m)     (n)        (m)      ^          ^      (n)
                               |          |
                             must be the same
```

The row and column limits of the result (m x n), as well as the size of the thread array needed therefore are simply defined by the output matrix size, which is defined by the rows of A and the columns of B. Therefore, `m=rowsA=rowsC` and `n=colsB=colsC`. Something like this:

```
template <typename T>
__global__ void mm_kernel(const T *A, const T *B, T *C, int m, int n, int colsA){

  int row = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y+threadIdx.y;
  int col = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  T sum = 0;
  if ((row < m) && (col < n)){
    for (int i = 0; i < colsA; i++) sum += A[colsA*row + i] * B[i*n+col];
    C[row*n+col] = sum;}
}
```

in your host code you would need to create a grid like this:

```
const int m = 1000; // determines size of output matrix
const int n = 2000; 
const int blkdim = 16;
dim3 dimBlock(blkdim,blkdim);
dim3 dimGrid((n+dimBlock.x-1)/dimBlock.x, (m+dimBlock.y-1)/dimBlock.y);
```

(all of above is coded in browser, not tested)

If you try to make a [shared-memory optimized version](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory), this becomes noticeably more complicated for non-square sizes.  But if performance is what you're after, you should use [CUBLAS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#abstract).

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you so much, it works perfectly